# Is there a function to find subarray in javascript with repeated elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sub-array

I am now writing a javascript to filter out arrays that contains a specific sub-array. Of course I can write the function by myself, but I am just curious if there are already some built-in function in javascript or other javascript library to do that, or if there are easy way to do that with just a few lines.

I found that I can use underscore.js if all the elements in the sub-array is unique. There is a intersection function and I can check the lenght after intersection to see if the length are correct. However, that function fails if there are repeated values in the sub-array.

For example,

```
_.intersection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 1]);
```

This will return [1, 2] and by checking the length I will know this array contains the sub-array.

However, when there are repeated values in the sub-array,

```
_.intersection([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], [1, 1, 2]);
_.intersection([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 2]);
```

Both will return [1, 2] and the cases cannot be distinguished.

Is there other pre-built function I can use or is there a easy way to do the job within a few lines?

Comment: [1, 1, 2].filter(function without(v) { 
 return this.indexOf(v) === -1;
}, [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10]).length==0;

Comment: This method will result in the same error if [1,2,3,4] and [1,1,2] is used.

Comment: [1, 1, 2] and [1, 2] both produce true, is there a requirement i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function contains(a, b) {
    // sort arguments
    if(a.length < b.length) {
        var temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    // copy array
    a = a.slice();
    return b.every(function(elm) {
        var index = a.indexOf(elm);
        if(index !== -1) {
            // remove the found element
            a.splice(index, 1); 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

console.log(contains([1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10])); // logs false
console.log(contains([1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10])); // logs true
console.log(contains([1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], [1, 1, 2])); // logs false
console.log(contains([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], [1, 1, 2])); // logs true
```

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trearsh4/)**

Comment: Thanks. This is a working method and at least shorter than the one I wrote by myself. Yet, I want to see if there are quicker method. Will upvote and mark as correct if there are no other better answers in these few days.